# Wordpress Admin Login - constant redirect

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I am working with the temporary URL http://46.32.240.36/thamon.co.uk/newthamon/
and main domain http://www.thamon.co.uk

I have made a fully working website on the temporary URL using wordpress. After that I've created a fresh wordpress blog for main domain. In Dashboard I pointed the wordpress URL to be that of temporary url so that the main domain website simply loads up the website from temporary URL (at least I thought that's how it works).

Now the problem is, my temporary URL website crashed the front page  and nothing opens on the page anymore and both temporary URL/wp-login.php and main url/wp-login.php don't allow me to login. I put the login details for one website, after I press Log In it redirects me to the other. And back again. So it's a loop now.

Also both of the pages give me 404 if I try to open website-name/admin

So help me figure out please:

1. Why did my temporary URL website crashed into this mess?
2. How to resolve the login issue?
3. How to stop redirecting from 1 page to another.

Comment: Sounds like you might need to change some values in the wp_options table in the database. If you take a look in that table it should be pretty apparent which values need changing.

Comment: your login is located here www.thamon.co.uk/wp-admin but there is a plugin affecting the login page, ftp in and delete all plugins and if you cant log in still all the themes except 2015. The dashboard/ setup/ db values files all need to point to your main url and you need to check them all after putting in the wrong url (for your installed plugins too, when you have updated all these values, you can reinstall the plugins)

Comment: thanks guys for the suggestions. The problem was in the incorrect wordpress installation. There was an issue with ftp subfolders with clean wordpress install and pre-made website install. Placing them in separate folders helped resolve the login issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks guys for the suggestions. The problem was in the incorrect wordpress installation. There was an issue with ftp subfolders with clean wordpress install and pre-made website install. Placing them in separate folders helped resolve the login issue.